# Convert a string to

Tags: vb.net, string, winforms

For example i have a program with 10 buttons and when i press a random one its name is saved to a string and i want to add 1 to the button's name for example if i pressed button1 ill alter the string to say button2 but now i cant use that string because it cant convert string to system.windows.forms.buttons, i have already tried the Me.Controls bu it didnt work for me.

Example:

```
dim stringy as string
dim integr as integer
dim buton as button

sub procedureee
stringy = stringy.remove(0,6)
integr = val(stringy) + 1
stringy = "Button" & integr
button.backcolor = white
end sub


Button1_Click
stringy = button1
procedureee
```

/* EDIT */

Im sorry i think i didnt make my sefl clear, everything in this code works for me except "stringy = button1" it says that string cannot be converted to system.windows.forms.button but thats exactly what i want to do, i have a program with 100 buttons and when any button is pressed it sets the value of ("Dim local as button") the variable local= the button pressed, and it works so i take that button.name and remove 1 from it so i get the value of the button above(PS: i have the buttons on a grid and vertically its from 1 to 10 and if i remove 1 il get the name of the button abore ex: button1gA3 becomes Button1gA2) but when i try to do this local2 = stringy it gives me that message(string cannot be converted to system.windows.forms.button) anyone knows how to solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go ...

```
  Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, Button2.click

    Dim FullButtonName As String = sender.text

    Dim ButtonsNumber As String = FullButtonName.Replace("Button", "").Trim

    Dim NewButtonNumber As Integer = CType(ButtonsNumber, Integer) + 1

    sender.text = "Button " & NewButtonNumber.ToString

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FindControl()` to find a control by name. Note that it is not recursive, and so you'll need to call this method on the direct parent that contains your buttons.